# Github Co-Pilot and Co-Pilot chat in Visual Studio 2022 is not showing me commands when I enter a /

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I have GitHub Copilot 1.147.0.0 (v1.147.0.0@218a5ecac) Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.8.4

When I click the / button in the light grey area textbox nothing happens, co-pilot doesn't show me any commands.

[image]

or when I right click in the code editor and select ask co-pilot and I type the / no commands are displayed

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, my assumption is that co-pilot will show me a list of commands I can use.

I have re-started my pc, updated vs with vs installer, and checked that my extensions are up to date.  Also in the github copilot output window it says my account is connected.

Any help or clarification is appreciated, thanks!